# Is it possible to create elements using Bokeh widget DIV that respond to bokeh server commands?

Tags: python, bokeh

I've been using Bokeh's datatable, but there are a few things I'd like to do that I don't know how to accomplish using the DataTable class. For example, I don't think it's possible add icons (or any images) to different rows, or setting the table to single selection only. So, I've been thinking about implementing just a HTML table, and writing it with the DIV widget.

However, I'd still like to add interactive features to the table, like buttons, or the icons mentioned above. Then, when an event is generated (e.g. onClick), that event is captured by the Bokeh server, and I can write the handlers in Python to do things such as modifying the data in ColumnDataSource, for example.

Is this possible? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the appropriate way to achieve what you want is to create a custom widget:

- [Extending Bokeh Documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/advanced/extensions.html#extending-bokeh)
- [Custom Widget Examples](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/advanced/extensions.html#examples)

So I think you need to override some behaviors in the Datatable widget. You can see an example with the [**Ion Range Slider - Range**](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/advanced/extensions/widget.html#ug-advanced-extensions-examples-widget):

Python code

```py
"""Example implementation of two double ended sliders as extension widgets"""
from bokeh.core.properties import Bool, Float, Tuple
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, InputWidget, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure


class IonRangeSlider(InputWidget):
    # The special class attribute ``__implementation__`` should contain a string
    # of JavaScript or TypeScript code that implements the web browser
    # side of the custom extension model or a string name of a file with the implementation.

    __implementation__ = "ion_range_slider.ts"
    __javascript__ = [
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js",
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.4/js/ion.rangeSlider.js",
    ]

    # Below are all the "properties" for this model. Bokeh properties are
    # class attributes that define the fields (and their types) that can be
    # communicated automatically between Python and the browser. Properties
    # also support type validation. More information about properties in
    # can be found here:
    #
    #    https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/properties.html#bokeh-core-properties

    disable = Bool(default=True, help="""
    Enable or disable the slider.
    """)

    grid = Bool(default=True, help="""
    Show or hide the grid beneath the slider.
    """)

    start = Float(default=0, help="""
    The minimum allowable value.
    """)

    end = Float(default=1, help="""
    The maximum allowable value.
    """)

    range = Tuple(Float, Float, help="""
    The start and end values for the range.
    """)

    step = Float(default=0.1, help="""
    The step between consecutive values.
    """)

x = [x*0.005 for x in range(2, 198)]
y = x

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = figure(width=400, height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6, color='#ed5565')

callback_single = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    const f = cb_obj.value
    const x = source.data.x
    const y = Array.from(x, (x) => Math.pow(x, f))
    source.data = {x, y}
""")

callback_ion = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    const {data} = source
    const f = cb_obj.range
    const pow = (Math.log(data.y[100]) / Math.log(data.x[100]))
    const delta = (f[1] - f[0]) / data.x.length
    const x = Array.from(data.x, (x, i) => delta*i + f[0])
    const y = Array.from(x, (x) => Math.pow(x, pow))
    source.data = {x, y}
""")

slider = Slider(start=0, end=5, step=0.1, value=1, title="Bokeh Slider - Power")
slider.js_on_change('value', callback_single)

ion_range_slider = IonRangeSlider(start=0.01, end=0.99, step=0.01, range=(min(x), max(x)),
    title='Ion Range Slider - Range')
ion_range_slider.js_on_change('range', callback_ion)

show(column(plot, slider, ion_range_slider))
```

TypeScript for IonRangeSlider:

```js
// The "core/properties" module has all the property types
import * as p from "core/properties"

// HTML construction and manipulation functions
import {div, input, StyleSheetLike, ImportedStyleSheet} from "core/dom"

// We will subclass in JavaScript from the same class that was subclassed
// from in Python
import {InputWidget, InputWidgetView} from "models/widgets/input_widget"

declare function jQuery(...args: any[]): any

export type SliderData = {from: number, to: number}

// This model will actually need to render things, so we must provide
// view. The LayoutDOM model has a view already, so we will start with that
export class IonRangeSliderView extends InputWidgetView {
declare model: IonRangeSlider

override stylesheets(): StyleSheetLike[] {
    return [
    ...super.stylesheets(),
    new ImportedStyleSheet("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.4/css/ion.rangeSlider.css"),
    new ImportedStyleSheet("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.4/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.min.css"),
    ]
}

private value_el?: HTMLInputElement

override render(): void {
    // BokehJS Views create <div> elements by default, accessible as this.el.
    // Many Bokeh views ignore this default <div>, and instead do things
    // like draw to the HTML canvas. In this case though, we change the
    // contents of the <div>, based on the current slider value.
    super.render()

    if (this.model.title != null) {
    this.value_el = input({type: "text", class: "bk-input", readonly: true, style: {marginBottom: "5px"}})
    this.group_el.appendChild(this.value_el)
    }

    this.input_el = input({type: "text"})
    this.group_el.appendChild(div({style: {width: "100%"}}, this.input_el))

    // Set up parameters
    const max = this.model.end
    const min = this.model.start
    const [from, to] = this.model.range ?? [max, min]
    const opts = {
    type: "double",
    grid: this.model.grid,
    min,
    max,
    from,
    to,
    step: this.model.step ?? (max - min)/50,
    disable: this.model.disabled,
    onChange: (data: SliderData) => this.slide(data),
    onFinish: (data: SliderData) => this.slidestop(data),
    }

    jQuery(this.input_el).ionRangeSlider(opts)
    if (this.value_el != null)
    this.value_el.value = `${from} - ${to}`
}

slidestop(_data: SliderData): void {
}

slide({from, to}: SliderData): void {
    if (this.value_el != null)
    this.value_el.value = `${from} - ${to}`

    this.model.range = [from, to]
}
}

export namespace IonRangeSlider {
export type Attrs = p.AttrsOf<Props>

export type Props = InputWidget.Props & {
    range: p.Property<[number, number] | null>
    start: p.Property<number>
    end: p.Property<number>
    step: p.Property<number | null>
    grid: p.Property<boolean>
}
}

export interface IonRangeSlider extends IonRangeSlider.Attrs {}

export class IonRangeSlider extends InputWidget {
declare properties: IonRangeSlider.Props
declare __view_type__: IonRangeSliderView

constructor(attrs?: Partial<IonRangeSlider.Attrs>) {
    super(attrs)
}

static {
    // If there is an associated view, this is boilerplate.
    this.prototype.default_view = IonRangeSliderView

    // The this.define block adds corresponding "properties" to the JS model. These
    // should basically line up 1-1 with the Python model class. Most property
    // types have counterparts, e.g. bokeh.core.properties.String will be
    // String in the JS implementation. Where the JS type system is not yet
    // as rich, you can use p.Any as a "wildcard" property type.
    this.define<IonRangeSlider.Props>(({Boolean, Number, Tuple, Nullable}) => ({
    range: [ Nullable(Tuple(Number, Number)), null ],
    start: [ Number, 0 ],
    end:   [ Number, 1 ],
    step:  [ Nullable(Number), 0.1 ],
    grid:  [ Boolean, true ],
    }))
}
}
```

Comment: Your links are already dead. This is why stack overflow has a policy of putting relevant text to the answer IN the response...